# Can i use REST like one request and periodic response?

Tags: rest

I'm curious about the method. for example.

**Client** :  [POST] "Give me your cpu usage"

**Server** : OK I will give you the information periodically.

```
         { "cpu_usage" : "20" }
         { "cpu_usage" : "21" }
         .
         .
         .
         { "cpu_usage" : "22" }
         { "cpu_usage" : "20" }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Push_technology&section=2 .

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this with HTTP. See 'long polling' or `multipart/event-stream` for more information.

This doesn't really fall in the typical REST design though.

Comment: Thank you. "long polling" key word is very helpful.